# PyQt5 Roles and the MVC

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt, pyqt5

I was trying to code a small ToDo app and stumbled upon lack of understanding of how Model handles Roles, I mean, how does it differentiate one Role from another one? Does it, like, check out all of them at the same time?

I would be glad to quench my curiosity

```
class TodoModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):

    """ Model for handling data"""

    def __init__(self, todos=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TodoModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.todos = todos or []

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole: #That Line
            status, text = self.todos[index.row()]
            return text
        
        if role == Qt.DecorationRole: #And This One
            status, text = self.todos[index.row()]
            if status:
                return tick

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.todos)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roles serve to store and access to a type of information of a certain item. The developers of Qt realized that there is basic information so it established basic roles through [`Qt.ItemDataRole`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum):

[image]

<sup>(there are more roles, to see them use the link)</sup>

As are the pre-established roles, then default delegates use it to obtain the information to paint the item.

For more information check [Model/View Programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html)